# CASE on two rows with identical IDs but different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table. What I need is an sql query that will analyze two/more rows with the same id and: (1) CASE 'Result' is the same for both rows, print 'Passed'; (2) CASE 'Result' is not the same for both rows, print 'Failed'.

```
ID  Result  
73  2000    Passed
73  2000    
43  2000    Failed
43  1003
```

[image]

Is it all possible??

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Stack overflow. You need provide table structure, data and expected output in question to get better answers.

Comment: How about there are more than two rows with identical IDs but different values

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Result <> t1.Result);
```

Another option uses aggregation:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Result) = 1;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per id, then use `group by`:

```
select id,
       (case when min(result) = max(result) then 'Passed'
             else 'Failed'
        end) as flag
from t
group by id;
```

If you want the value on *all* rows of your original table, then it is simple:

```
select id,
       (case when not exists (select 1
                              from t t2
                              where t2.result) = t.result
                             )
             then 'Passed' else 'Failed'
        end) as flag
from t
group by id;
```

However, putting the result on *one* row is problematic.  There is no way to distinguish the rows, so it is more challenging (not impossible, but I suspect one of the above solves your real problem).

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
select id, case when count (distinct result)=1 then 'Passed' else 'Failed' end
group by id
```